# Express a language containing the words with an odd amount of 0's using the languages $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$

Tags: formal-languages

This is a homework question and after struggling with it for a while, I have decided to ask for help here.

The task is to construct a language over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ consisting of precisely those words $w$ with the property that $\#_0(w)$ is an odd number, i.e. the count of 0's in those words is odd (eg. $010,10011,00$ would all be words in this language). This language must be constructed using the languages $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ and a finite number of the following operations: union, intersection, set difference, complement, Kleene star, Kleene plus, concatenation and reverse. It's clear to me that I can equivalently construct a language with words whose count of 0 is even and then consider the complement. However, I cannot seem to come up with a way that can capture the parity of the amount a certain symbol appears in a word.

Answer (score 1):

The following language is the language of even number of 0's: $$ \{1\}^*\cdot (\{0\}\cdot \{1\}^*\cdot\{0\}\cdot \{1\}^*)^*$$

I leave correctness to you. Then, you can complement by taking its difference from the set of all words:

$$ (\{0\} \cup \{1\})^*\setminus (\{1\}^*\cdot (\{0\}\cdot \{1\}^*\cdot\{0\}\cdot \{1\}^*)^*)$$

Also, it is not hard to obtain a representation of the language without using complementation.

**Hint:** think regular expressions that do not have $\epsilon$ in their syntax.